# Opinions on planning and avoiding data redundancy

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, database-design

I am currently going to be designing an app in vb.net to work with an access back-end database.  I have been trying to think of ways to reduce down data redundancy
and I have an example scenario below:

Lets imagine, for an example purpose, I have a customers table and need to highlight all customers in WI and send them a letter.  The customers table would
contain all the customers and properties associated with customers (Name, Address, Etc) so we would query for where the state is "WI" in the table.  Then we would 
take the results of that data, and append it into a table with a "completion" indicator (So from 'CUSTOMERS' to say 'WI_LETTERS' table).

Lets assume some processing needs to be done so when its completed, mark a field in that table as 'complete', then allow the letters to be printed with 
a mail merge. (SELECT FROM 'WI_LETTERS' WHERE INDICATOR = COMPLETE).

That item is now completed and done.  But lets say, that every odd year (2013) we also send a notice to everyone in the table with a state of "WI".  We now query the
customers table when the year is odd and the customer's state is "WI".  Then append that data into a table called 'notices' with a completion indicator
and it is marked complete.

This seems to keep the data "task-based" as the data is based solely around the task at hand.  However, isn't this considered redundant data?  This setup means there
can be one transaction type to many accounts (even multiple times to the same account year after year), but shouldn't it be one account to many transactions?
How is the design of this made better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You certainly don't want to start creating new tables for *each individual task* you perform. You may want to create several different tables for different ***types* of tasks** if the information you need to track (and hence the columns in those tables) will be quite different between the different types of tasks, but those tables should be used for *all* tasks of that particular type. You can maintain a field in those tables to identify the *individual task* to which each record applies (e.g., [campaign_id] for Marketing campaign mailouts, or [mail_batch_id], or similar).
2. You **definitely** don't want to start creating new tables like [WI_letters] that are segregated by State (or *any* client attribute). You already have the customers' State in the [Customers] table so the only customer-related attribute you need in your [Letters] table is the [CustomerID]. If you frequently want to see a list of Letters for Customers in Wisconsin then you can always create a saved `Query` (often called a `View` in other database systems) named [WI_Letters] that looks like

   SELECT * FROM Letters INNER JOIN Customers ON Customers.CustomerID=Letters.CustomerID
   WHERE Customers.State="WI"

Comment: Ok, the customers table is over 300,000 records, does this make a difference? it seems very slow to index in the first place, and a long time to load into a datagridview at all, which is perhaps why things were originally designed that way.

Comment: @JasonBayldon Certainly the total number of records in the database will have some impact on performance, but 300K records in an Access table is not uncommon. Having appropriate indexes is always important, and I'm a bit puzzled when you say "it seems very slow to index in the first place", because indexing is something that is applied to a table *once* (when the table is created, or when the indexing strategy is changed), and thereafter the database engine only has to *maintain* the indexes, not create them all over again. Please explain.

Comment: Right, I apologize, I used that term incorrectly.  I was confused at first, but it appears the source table in the example (which is technically out of my control)  is reimported daily (had it linked) and the indexing is reset to none after the system drops the table and recreates it.I suppose I should just import it myself daily and apply indexing programatically.  Thanks for all your help!